# Oracle select query to string in java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, select

I have a select query in oracle that give me 1 value output

for example:

```
Date:

2018-01-01
```

How can I use this query in java and put it into a string?
I use this code and I got blank output:

```
import java.sql.*;  
class InsertPrepared{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
try{  
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","oracle");  

PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("select DateColumn from blabla");  
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();  
while(rs.next()){  
System.out.println(rs.getString("DateColumn"));  
}  

con.close();  

}catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  

}  
}
```

Comment: if your table is actually named BLABLA did you try to pass it in uppercase when preparing your statement?

Comment: Maybe you added data to your table in another session, where your query now works; but didn't commit? Also, do not create your own objects in the `SYSTEM` schema, or any other built-in schema - create a new user and do all your work under that.

Comment: what is the output of the same query when you run from sql plus?

Comment: Vic, I tried and it's doesn't work. Gagan Singh the output is 2018-01-01

Comment: Please check using the exact same query in a sql terminal.
After that put breakpoint at your System.out.println and check that you actually get a resultSet back. That also allows you to inspect the content of ResultSet.
This should be debugging 101..

Comment: I have connection problem. because I can't see any table in the current schema. but if I connect to the previous schema I can see anything. 
Someone know How I can refresh the connection?